# Unicode Emojis in transparent text are visible in IE12 / Edge

Tags: html, css, unicode, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I'm looking for a workaround for the following problem: Unicode Emojis in an element with transparent foreground color are still displayed in Edge.

```css
.text, .select {
 color: transparent;
}

.text::selection {
 color: transparent;
 background-color: highlight;
}

.text::-moz-selection {
 color: transparent;
 background-color: highlight;
}
```

```html
Here is the test text:
<p class="text">This  should be invisible!</p>
<p>Please select me<span class="select"> (should only show when selected)</span>!</p>
```

Setting the opacity of the element is not an option since i need to display a background image.

**EDIT:** I also just noticed a very weird behavior of Firefox: the emoji is hidden as long as nothing of the same element is selected. As soon as some part of the surrounding element is selected, the emoji shows up even though the rest of the text remains hidden. Also the selected text is not transparent as defined in the css. `::-moz-selection` doesn't help either.

**EDIT 2:**
I had an idea to change the font-family to something which doesn't get displayed but I haven't had any luck. `font-family: none;` obviously doesn't work because of a default fallback. I would need an empty font which has empty characters for all unicode emojis. Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried putting the text in span with the visibilty: hidden.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility

Comment: yes, i have tried that. same result as with opacity: also hides the background image.